# How to run a program behind all other running programs using vbs?

Tags: vbscript

This code works great. It opens the site in the chrome tab:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Return = WshShell.Run("chrome.exe stackoverflow.com " & WScript.ScriptFullName, 0, false)
```

But is it possible to open the same browser tab behind all other running programs?

[image]What I mean saying behind. Chrome tab is behind the exel window.

Comment: For your second question, you'll need to surround the program and path in double quotes:
`Return = WshShell.Run("""C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"" stackoverflow.com " & WScript.ScriptFullName, 0, false)`

Comment: What do you mean "behind"? As in hidden or as in lower in the stack of windows?

Comment: @Nathan Rice, I added "behind" example in the post.

Answer (score 1):

From Help

> Runs a program in a new process.
>
> ```
> object.Run(strCommand, [intWindowStyle], [bWaitOnReturn])
> ```
>
> **Arguments**
>
> object `WshShell` object.
>
> **strCommand**   String value indicating the command line you want to run. You must include any parameters you want to pass to the
>   executable file.
>
> **intWindowStyle**
>
> Optional. Integer value indicating the appearance of the program's
>   window. Note that not all programs make use of this information.
>
> **bWaitOnReturn**
>
> Optional. Boolean value indicating whether the script should wait for
>   the program to finish executing before continuing to the next
>   statement in your script. If set to true, script execution halts until
>   the program finishes, and Run returns any error code returned by the
>   program. If set to false (the default), the Run method returns
>   immediately after starting the program, automatically returning 0 (not
>   to be interpreted as an error code).
>
> **Remarks**
>
> The Run method returns an integer. The Run method starts a program
>   running in a new Windows process. You can have your script wait for
>   the program to finish execution before continuing. This allows you to
>   run scripts and programs synchronously. Environment variables within
>   the argument `strCommand` are automatically expanded. If a file type
>   has been properly registered to a particular program, calling run on a
>   file of that type executes the program. For example, if Word is
>   installed on your computer system, calling Run on a *.doc file starts
>   Word and loads the document. The following table lists the available
>   settings for `intWindowStyle`.
>
> **intWindowStyle  Description**
>
> ```
> 0
>  Hides the window and activates another window.
>
> 1
>  Activates and displays a window. If the window is minimized or maximized, the system restores it to its original size and position. An application should specify this flag when displaying the window for the first time.
>
> 2
>  Activates the window and displays it as a minimized window. 
>
> 3
>  Activates the window and displays it as a maximized window. 
>
> 4
>  Displays a window in its most recent size and position. The active window remains active.
>
> 5
>  Activates the window and displays it in its current size and position.
>
> 6
>  Minimizes the specified window and activates the next top-level window in the Z order.
>
> 7
>  Displays the window as a minimized window. The active window remains active.
>
> 8
>  Displays the window in its current state. The active window remains active.
>
> 9
>  Activates and displays the window. If the window is minimized or maximized, the system restores it to its original size and position. An application should specify this flag when restoring a minimized window.
>
> 10
>  Sets the show-state based on the state of the program that started the application.
> ```
>
> The following VBScript code opens a copy of the currently running
>   script with Notepad.
>
> ```
> Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
> WshShell.Run "%windir%\notepad " & WScript.ScriptFullName
> ```
>
> The following VBScript code does the same thing, except it specifies
>   the window type, waits for Notepad to be shut down by the user, and
>   saves the error code returned from Notepad when it is shut down.
>
> ```
> Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
> Return = WshShell.Run("notepad " & WScript.ScriptFullName, 1, true)
> ```
>
> The following VBScript code opens a command window, changes to the
>   path to C:\ , and executes the DIR command.
>
> ```
> Dim oShell
> Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WSCript.shell")
> oShell.run "cmd /K CD C:\ & Dir"
> Set oShell = Nothing
> ```
>
> **Applies To:**
>
> ```
> WshShell Object
> ```